# Sidebar toggle close and open Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to toggle the sidebar options, ie if I click on `Location`, its sub-items should be displayed. If I click on `Device`, its options should be displayed.

```
<div class="span3">
    <li>
        <a href="#location">Location</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#region">Region</a></li>
            <li><a href="#country">Country</a></li>
            <li><a href="#state">State</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#device">Device</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#gateway-unit">Gateway Unit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#modbus-unit">Modbus Unit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#meter-unit">Meter Unit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#user">Software User</a></li>
    <li><a href="#global-parameters">Global Parameters</a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try anything.... look at the click event handler

Comment: also `<div class="span3">` should be `<ul class="span3">`

Comment: .toggle function. but why div should be replaced by ul?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xjUAK/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<ul class="span3 navigation">
    <li>
        <a href="#location">Location</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#region">Region</a></li>
            <li><a href="#country">Country</a></li>
            <li><a href="#state">State</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#device">Device</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#gateway-unit">Gateway Unit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#modbus-unit">Modbus Unit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#meter-unit">Meter Unit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#user">Software User</a></li>
    <li><a href="#global-parameters">Global Parameters</a></li>
</ul>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $uls = $('.navigation ul').hide();
    $('.navigation li:has(ul) > a').click(function(){
        var $ul = $(this).next('ul').show();
        $uls.not($ul).hide();
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xjUAK/)

Comment: I tried your [jsfiddle link](jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xjUAK/1). It does works, but when I click on its sub-items, it gets closed. Why's that?